# Empty message displayed in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, django, angular-material

Whatever I try with ng-repeat, it always returns empty like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]">{{ n }}</div>
```

It is printing 3 times but print empty message.

Libraries - Angular 1.4.8, angular-material - 1.0.3

Reason:
It works with direct html file, but if I serve the same html with Django, it loops 3 times but shows empty message. So, how to make it work with Django ?

Comment: @arainone check the answer

Answer (score 1):

Starting from **Angular 1.3 and above** `ng-repeat` directive should be located **inside a `Controller`**

After trying in 2 different fiddle:

- [Angular 1.1](http://jsfiddle.net/5xjxe0fw/7/): It works out of the box, without even having to declare a `Controller`
- [Angular 1.4](http://jsfiddle.net/5xjxe0fw/10/): At first it didn't work if you just declare `ng-repeat`. But if it happens to exist a `$scope`, then it works. So you need to have a `Controller`

#### Angular 1.2 and below:

**Html:**

    `<div ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]">{{ n }}</div>`

---

#### Angular 1.3 and above:

**Html:**

    `<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]">{{ n }}</div>
    </div>Js:`

**Javascript**

(you need a `$scope`, so an empty `Controller` is enough):

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

Comment: Why do you need track by in angular 1.3?

Comment: I tried it in a fiddle and forgot to remove it. That's done now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should work according to the information you have given. It does not have anything to do with material.

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]">
    <div layout="row" flex class="content-wrapper">
        <h1>  {{ n }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED:**

With angular 1.3 and above version you should define controller globally like this,

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}])
```

Here is the working [`Application`](https://plnkr.co/edit/TaypIkcdKcC4PnQIkzZ1?p=preview)

Updated [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/2vt1mL59/)